# How do I use eval-after-load exactly?

Tags: eval-after-load

I don't know how to check if `eval-after-load` works or not.

I used the following code to check if FORM is loaded

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'org
  (message "loaded!"))
```

After the above is evaluated, I tried the following

1. reload org buffer
2. `(require 'org)`
3. `(load-file "path/to/org")`

None of the above display `"loaded!"` message.

`(message "loaded!")` is found in `after-load-alist`.

the question is

1. how do I use `eval-after-load` and `with-eval-after-load`.
2. How do I check if `FORM` is loaded.

Comment: It seems you already have `(require 'org)` before your code is evaluated. You can try to restart emacs to check if it message.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: You can use `(featurep 'org)` to see if org is already loaded. If it is, then the body of `eval-after-load` is evaluated immediately.

Comment: You had several typos in your question, substituting `eval-load-after` (which doesn't exist) for `eval-after-load`. Dunno whether that represents only a typo in your question or is behind the problem you think you're seeing. I corrected the question typo.

Comment: `with-eval-after-load` is the same as `eval-after-load`, except that it doesn't evaluate the first arg.